# get crontab time as input from user, and pass it to Ansible

Tags: ansible, cron

I need to take the var crontab_time as input from the user and then pass it to Ansible to use it with module 'cron',  but when input contain asterisks symbol I get error: `bad hour\nerrors in crontab file, can't install.\n`

I think I need to pass it as string and not as a symbol but I'm not sure how

This is my read statement: `read -p "Enter the time to run the script in the crontab (ex: * 01 * * *): " crontab_duration`

And this is the error:
 `bad hour\nerrors in crontab file, can't install.\n`

Comment: The crontab module takes individual fields (hour, day, etc) so you need to split that input and assign each part to right field.  `min: (crontab_duration | split(' '))[0]` (untested).

Answer (score 1):

The following asks for the cron expression and sets the cron for user. Adapt to your own needs. Bonus point with `vars_prompt`: the interaction will only pop up if the var does not exist. Hence you can bypass the question by calling your playbook with `-e "cron_expression='1 1 1 * *'"`

The example `cron.yml` playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: set a cron with user input if needed
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    cron_command: /usr/bin/true 2>&1 > /dev/null

    cron_fields: "{{ cron_expression | split() }}"

    cron_minute: "{{ cron_fields[0] }}"
    cron_hour: "{{ cron_fields[1]  }}"
    cron_day: "{{ cron_fields[2] }}"
    cron_month: "{{ cron_fields[3] }}"
    cron_weekday: "{{ cron_fields[4] }}"

  vars_prompt:
    - name: cron_expression
      prompt: "Please enter cron expression (e.g. * 1 * * *)"
      private: no

  tasks:
    - name: Dumb validation (make your better own)
      vars:
        field_num: "{{ cron_fields | length }}"
        target_num: 5
      ansible.builtin.assert:
        that:
          - field_num | int == target_num | int
        fail_msg: "The cron expression you entered contains {{ field_num }} fields instead of {{ target_num }}"

    - name: Make sure cron is set with the correct time
      ansible.builtin.cron:
        name: "An example cron"
        minute: "{{ cron_minute }}"
        hour: "{{ cron_hour }}"
        day: "{{ cron_day }}"
        month: "{{ cron_month }}"
        weekday: "{{ cron_weekday }}"
        job: "{{ cron_command }}"
```

Example runs:

```
$ ansible-playbook cron.yml
Please enter cron expression (e.g. * 1 * * *): 1 2 1 1 *

PLAY [set a cron with user input if needed] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Dumb validation (make your better own)] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All assertions passed"
}

TASK [Make sure cron is set with the correct time] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

$ ansible-playbook cron.yml -e "cron_expression='0 1 * * 1'"

PLAY [set a cron with user input if needed] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Dumb validation (make your better own)] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All assertions passed"
}

TASK [Make sure cron is set with the correct time] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```